# Exclude lib folder from solution wide analysis resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper, rider

R# solution wide analysis resharper has been trying to suggest changes in bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.js, jquery.min.js and... what not.

> IMHO it should be handled by R# by default, Can we disable it?
>
> IMHO with invention of Rosylyn, must come out or R# addiction ;-)

EDIT: Thanks to @Barr
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is noted in [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#exclude_items) forums, I will provide you, and whoever will need it further, here with a minimize explanation:

In order to choose which files will be included in solution wide analysis:

- Select **ReSharper** | **Options** in the main menu, then choose **Code Inspection** | **Settings** on the left.
- In the left part of the **Elements to skip** section, you can specify files or folders to be ignored by the code inspection.
- In the right part of this section, you can specify masks (e.g. *.cs) that will exclude all matching files in the solution from code inspection.
- Click **Save** to apply the modifications and let ReSharper choose where to save them, or save the modifications to a specific settings layer using the **Save To** drop-down list.

*Side Note*:

Please follow [Managing and Sharing ReSharper Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html) if you want to share your resharper solution settings.